# scanner neglecting white spaces in the beginning

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stdin, stdio

I am using scanner to get input of a String.My code is as below

```
String s=scan.next();
if(scan.hasNext()){
    s +=scan.nextLine();
}
```

But the problem is it is not reading the white spaces in the beginning.

Example

```
Input            :    Hello   World

Output should be :    Hello   World

Output is        :Hello   World
```

Please clarify what is the mistake and help me rectify.

Comment: use scan.nextLine();

Answer (score 1):

`next()` method is used to let us get next word (token) without preceding delimiters. Default delimiter used by Scanner is *one or more whitespace* so it was ignored by design.

If you want `s` to hold entire line (or rest of current line) including delimiters then skip `next()` and use only `nextLine()`.

```
String s = scan.hasNextLine() ? scan.nextLine() : "";
```

But be careful about problem which is often faced when we mix `next` and `nextLine` described in: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0):

Read the scanner [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

`scan.next()` breaks the input into tokens based on white space.

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace.

Try this:

```
String s="";
        if(scan.hasNext()){
        s +=scan.nextLine();
    }
```